# How to store data that depends on dynamic number of parameters

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I can't get my head around this problem. I'm trying to find a good way to store this in a PostgreSQL database.

Each client of my company needs to visualize data that depends on a dynamic number of parameters.

Example:

**clientA** wants to store the ***prices of its products***. A price is defined by `product_id` and `store_id`. I need a way to query the database, giving the `product_id` and `store_id` and get back a `price`.

**clientB** wants to store the ***power of its cars***. A power is defined by `car_id`, `car_variation` and `fuel_type`. I need a way to query the database, giving the `car_id`, `car_variation` and `fuel_type` and get back a `power`.

Each client must be able to define its own "dimensions" or "parameters" that define the data they want to vizualize.

I can either :

- put all the data in the same table, with A LOT of empty columns for each row ==> seems dumb
- create a new table for each client, with only the right columns in each of them? I'm not used to having a table per client but maybe it's the way to go
- a third way I did not think of that tackles this exact problem

Comment: Have you considered an EAV model? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: Depends on information that's not in our question. How many clients, how many dimensions, how many rows, how much traffic, insert / update / delete, priorities  ...

Comment: create one table with columns common to all clients and a JSONB column to store the client specific attributes and values

Comment: @McNets do you think the EAV model works? The main thing I need is querying according to multiple attributes value (given these attributes values, what is the entity? Not sure EAV is made for this).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yeah you're right. Around 100 thousand rows, a few new clients a week (B2B company) and a few dozens for now, not a lot of traffic, mainly read operations once it's written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you want a table that has a composite type as part of the key.

```
create extension hstore;

create table stats (client int, key hstore, value text , primary key (client, key));


insert into stats values 
  (1,'"product"=>"gum","store"=>"711"','USD 0.49')
 ,(1,'"product"=>"soda","store"=>"711"','USD 0.99')
 ,(2,'"vehicle"=>"prefect 351","fuel"=>"nitromethane"','950kW')
 ,(2,'"vehicle"=>"prefect 351","fuel"=>"ULP-97RON"','600kW')
;

select * from stats where client=2 and key=hstore(array['vehicle','prefect 351','fuel','nitromethane']);
```

or perhaps with the value column as hstore also, perhaps he wants to store "loudness" and "power"

Comment: Nowadays I would probably go for a `JSONB` column, rather than hstore

Comment: Ok so basically a `JSONB` or `hstore` to store all varying data. That may work since JSONB can be indexed… May validate this answer just waiting to see if smth else comes up

Comment: I chose hstore because it reorders the elements, meaning `'{"a"=>"1","b"=>"2"}' = '{"b"=>"2","a"=>"1"}'` which is probably a useful feature. (for a key) you can do decomposed indexes on hstore too if needed.